# Use of ChatGPT is inappropriate for Robotics questions

Tags: support, announcement

Please note that as a stack exchange is evaluating a site wide policy, *Robotics* community members should avoid using ChatGPT to generate answers (and questions) here.

If you do not have the knowledge to know whether an answer generated using ChatGPT, or similar tools, is correct or not, you should not be answering that question.

The posting of content created by ChatGPT is considered *substantially harmful* to our community and to users who are asking and looking for correct answers.

References

- [Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/42473)
- [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)
- [Is there a list of ChatGPT discussions and policies for our sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384923/138432)